FusionCharts TimeSeries - Hour timestamp is one hour ahead?
While working with the TimeSeries part of FusionCharts I noticed the hour timestamp on the chart does not match up with the hour timestamp from the data, it adds one hour to each timestamp in the dataset.
Here is a picture of an example from the FusionCharts docs that exhibits the problem. You will notice that the first image has an hour timestamp of 8:00 AM with a data value of 121...
Image from FusionCharts that shows the datapoint 2017-6-1 08:00 with a value of 121
while the data has an hour timestamp of 06:00 with a data value of 121.
Image that shows the data, spesifically one point with the date 2017-6-1 06:00 and a value of 121
This is a link to that same page,
And this is a link to the dataset that the chart is using.
This is happening with every datapoint on the chart, not just the first.
I have tried to change the formatting of the schema, passing in different data sets, changing the version of FusionCharts I was using, and I've searched all over the FusionCharts docs/forums to try to find out why this is happening but nothing seemed to set the timestamp to the actual time that corresponds to the data value. Plus, this seems to be a recurring bug in all of the examples found on the FusionCharts website.
If someone could shed some light on the topic that would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!!
